# how do i prove this $S=\{(x,y,z): x^2 +4y^2 +4 z^2 -2x +16y +40z +113 <0\}$ is an open set

Tags: geometric-topology

[Elipsoide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Encvr.jpg)  
in the three-dimensional space, with the graph of the ellipsoid the set is open, but how do I prove it?

Comment: Let $f:X \to Y$ be continuous. If $U$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $X$. Does this help?

Comment: But what is $f^{-1}((-\infty, 0))$ and how does one show that is open?

Comment: @fleablood.   The topological definition of continuous is inverse images of open sets are open.

Comment: Brainfart.  Idiotically I was have trouble getting that $f^{-1}((-\infty,0)) = S$.  Don't know why I was haven't the glitch....

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x,y,z)$ is a polynomial of three variables, then $f$ is continuous. Since $f$ is continuous, what can we say about $f^{-1}(U)$ when $U\subset\Bbb R$ is open?